# Rendering a view of controller action from around_action callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, callback, controller

I'm rendering a js.erb partial which enables ajax functionality to like/dislike a restaurant dish. I recently came across the `around_action` callback and figured `yield` would help perform the controller action first and render the template second. Unfortunately I'm getting a `500 (Internal Server Error)` due to the `respond_to` never getting called.

The `respond_to` method works if I place it inside the controller action but not inside the callback. What am I doing wrong?

```
class DishesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_dish_and_restaurant
  around_action :render_vote_partial

  def like
    @dish.liked_by current_user
  end

  ...

  private
    def set_dish_and_restaurant
      @dish = Dish.find(params[:id])
    end

    def render_vote_partial
      yield
      respond_to { |format| format.js { render "vote.js.erb" } }
    end
end
```

**Console Error**

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template dishes/like, application/like with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/app/views"
  * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb:29:in `render_vote_partial'
```

Comment: could you post exception stack trace you get on the console please?

Comment: An action is called before, after or around rendering... It's not rendering... Responses should always be in actions.

Comment: True, trying to render from around_action is bad design , however I am trying to understand if it is technically not allowed. Which I had access to my dev machine right now to try it out.

Comment: @Shaunak Posted the console error. Based on Ruby Racer's comment should I not try to make the attempt to DRY out my controller actions and just place the `respond_to` actions in every one of them?

Comment: @CarlEdwards check my answer pls, and an update that attempts to explain your question about keeping things DRY

Comment: @Shaunak Saw it just after posting the comment in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so with your stack trace it is pretty clear what is happening. You have to understand the default rails behavior of convention over configuration.

As soon as you call `yield`, your controller action gets called. Now all controller actions by default look to render views with the same name as action, once the actions are done executing.

So calling `render_to` after `yield` doesn't make any sense, as controller action you *yielded to* has already called its render :)

In any case what you are trying to do is a bad design pattern, rendering views should be left to `actions`

> Update

Theoretically speaking : As you wish to keep things DRY  you could render the same view after each action by creating a common method calling it after every action. However, think about it, your render will have one line, and calling that same method will need one line too :) so where's the DRY.

In short, DRY should not be over done at the cost of simplicity. In my opinion **KISS** trumps **DRY** :)

Comment: Thanks. So should I not worry so much of keeping things DRY? Reason I ask is because I have 4 actions that render this template.

Comment: usually you should try and keep things dry, but not at the cost of simplicity. KISS trumps DRY :)