# Rails: How to automatically add a method before the end of each action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have actions that are supposed to render an index view with different contents. I tried `after_action` but it still looks for a specific view before running `render_index`:

```
after_action :render_index, except: [:index]

def index
  @items = Item.all
end

def fruits
  @items = Item.where(category: 'fruits')
  # render 'index'
end

def cars
  @items = Item.where(category: 'cars')
  # render 'index'
end

...a lot more

def render_index
  render 'index'
end
```

How can I add `render_index` just before each `end` statement so I don't have to write `render 'index'` over and over?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering a view of controller action from around\_action callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858077/rendering-a-view-of-controller-action-from-around-action-callback)

Comment: Can you not combine all those actions in a single action and have a route like `get /:category`? This will also remove a duplication of `@items = Item.where(...)` while having to write `render 'index'` only once.

Comment: a) there is nothing wrong with calling `render 'index'` all over the place b) what @tejasbubane said c) dont think about setting the render call in a before or after hook, thats a bad practice

Comment: You can't render in a method which runs after another method which already renders.

Comment: Each action has its own unique sub actions so I think it would be cleaner to have separate routes. Ok, I will just write render 'index' and other common methods repeatedly